# Group by array overlap in PrestoSQL

Tags: presto

Lets say I have a table with existing 3 column user_id, family_definition, family:

1. according to “apple” family definition, user_id 123 & 456 are same family
2. according to “orange” family definition, user_id 456 & 874 are same family
3. according to “banana” family definition, user_id 874 & 034 are same family
4. so now I want to create another column that group 123,456,874,034 as one family, 789 is second family, 478 is third family

| user_id | family_definition | family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | apple | 1 |
| 456 | apple | 1 |
| 789 | orange | 1 |
| 456 | orange | 2 |
| 874 | orange | 2 |
| 034 | banana | 6 |
| 874 | banana | 6 |
| 789 | banana | 7 |
| 478 | banana | 12 |

sample output as follow:

| user_id | family_definition | family | family_agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | apple | 1 | 1 |
| 456 | apple | 1 | 1 |
| 789 | orange | 1 | 2 |
| 456 | orange | 2 | 1 |
| 874 | orange | 2 | 1 |
| 034 | banana | 6 | 1 |
| 874 | banana | 6 | 1 |
| 789 | banana | 7 | 2 |
| 478 | banana | 12 | 3 |

Thought of using array_agg & array_overlap but my logic doesn't seem to work as well.